# How to add x-scheme-handler in GTK application?

Tags: gtk, gnome, meson-build, gnome-builder

Adding `MimeType=x-scheme-handler/xyz;` to data/package.desktop.in isn't helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the app has to be installed for the x-scheme-handler to be detected, merely running it from GNOME Builder won't help.

Steps for installation:

1. Click on the Build from the omnibar, followed by Export Bundle in the same dropdown.
2. Open a terminal in the directory that opened after the export was done.
3. Run `flatpak install yourapp.flatpak`

Thanks to developers in Matrix chatroom for helping out.